# How to get executing code's file's name in go?

Tags: go

Say I have a file:

i_want_this_name.go:

```
package main

func main(){
    filename := some_func() // should be "i_want_this_name"
}
```

How do I get the executing code's file's name in go?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the command can be found in `os.Args[0]` as states in the documentation for [the os package](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables):

> `var Args []string`
>
> Args hold the command-line arguments, starting with the program name.

To use it, do the following:

```
package main

import "os"

func main(){
    filename := os.Args[0]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "runtime"
)

func main() {
  _, fileName, lineNum, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
  fmt.Printf("%s: %d\n", fileName, lineNum)
}
```

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/3T8fr_Hist